# Change var of jQuery function in another file

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a paginator on my website, and I need add a button that allows show all results without pagination.

For the pagination, I have this script:

```
jQuery(function() 
{
    var items = $("article.inmueble");
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 5;

    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    jQuery("#paginador").pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

            items.hide() 
                 .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
});
```

This code is in `js/initialize_paginator.js`.

In my `index.php` I call this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/initialize_paginator.js"></script>
```

And in this `index.php` I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Ver todo</button>
```

How I can do to, when click this button, change the `var perPage = 5;` to (for example) `var perPage = 999999999;` to show all results?

Comment: Thanks for editing jurgemaister and sorry

Comment: `perPage` is only available in the specific ready handler scope. You could make global it by removing `var` statement

Answer (score 1):

Use perPage as global variable outside the jQuery(function()

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to initialize the pagination. Something like this

```
function paginate(items,numItems,perPage)
{
   items.slice(perPage).hide();

jQuery("#paginador").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

        items.hide() 
             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
});
}
```

And then use it like this `paginate($("article.inmueble"), $("article.inmueble").length, 5);` and **reinitialize** when needed with updated value, like in your case the click event of the btn with the perPage value 9999.

Hope this helps.